# LibreOffice after update from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, Blacked Toolbar Icon Background

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

With LibreOffice 5.2.0.4 after update from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, Blacked Toolbar Icon Background When Using Breeze Theme

[image]

Comment: Are you using a third party repository? Did you try adwaita or the default Ubuntu theme? Because of libreoffice just started using gtk3 libs to theme, you'll have to wait until they fix it in the next release.